# PHP to ASP.Net conversion

Tags: php, asp.net, vb.net

I am converting an old PHP porject over to ASP.Net (vb) and wondered if someone could point me in the right direction in order to convert this final snippet of code.

There are 3 functions that are called from within this and i ahve converted those already and to be honest is the session arrays that are giving me the headache.

I have thought about using Hashtables and DirecCasting but this was just confusing me further.

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

```
$response = array();

$messages = array();

if (!empty($_POST['cbox'])) {

    if (!empty($_SESSION['opsd_user_'.$_POST['cbox']])) {
        $messages = $_SESSION['opsd_user_'.$_POST['cbox']];
    }
} else 
{

    if (!empty($_POST['blist']) && $_POST['blist'] == 1) { getBList(); }

    if (!empty($_POST['initialize']) && $_POST['initialize'] == 1) { 
        getStatus(); 

        if (!empty($_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars'])) {
            $response['initialize'] = $_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars'];

            if (!empty($_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars']['openCBID']) && !empty($_SESSION['opsd_user_'.$_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars']['openCBID']])) {
            $messages = array_merge($messages,$_SESSION['opsd_user_'.$_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars']['openCBID']]);
            }
        }
    } else {

        if (empty($_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars'])) {
            $_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars'] = array();
        }

        if (!empty($_POST['sessionvars'])) {
            ksort($_POST['sessionvars']);
        } else {
            $_POST['sessionvars'] = '';
        }

        if (!empty($_POST['updatesession']) && $_POST['updatesession'] == 1) { 
            $_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars'] = $_POST['sessionvars'];
        }

        if ($_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars'] != $_POST['sessionvars']) {
            $response['updatesession'] = $_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars'];
        }

    }

    getLastTimestamp();
    fetchMessages();
}
```

Comment: First, do you understand what the code does?

Comment: Yes I am aware of what the code does, there are a number of ajax posts that come in and these are updated (some) into session variables. there are 3 distinct areas I am struggling with: 1 - $response['initialize'] = Session['opsd_sessionvars']; 
2 - ksort($_POST['sessionvars']);
3 - $messages = array_merge($messages,$_SESSION['opsd_user_'.$_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars']['openCBID']]);

Iam just not sure how to convert these, I think I have the rest already done

Comment: That you're struggling to convert sort and merge operations shows that you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) properties of the ASP.NET page. A simple find/replace of $_SESSION with Session in the page should work wonders, as should a replacement of $_POST with Request.Form.

Comment: OK I get that and will make the required changes but I dont get the following: 

`$messages = array_merge($messages,$_SESSION['opsd_user_'.$_SESSION['opsd_sessionvars']['openCBID']]);`

and

`ksort($_POST['sessionvars']);`

I have checked php.net but have not really been able to find ant .net equivalents.

Comment: If $messages is a string-keyed array, then the .NET equivalent is a Dictionary(String, *something*). The ksort() method is equivalent to pushing those same key-value pairs into a SortedDictionary(K,V) and iterating over it.